# Why does the click handler for this ExtJS action column not work?

Tags: extjs

I created an action column with an icon, and I want to hide the icon if the row being clicked is for the eval license.But the click event handler is not getting called?

```
xtype: 'actioncolumn',
text: 'Actions',
align: 'center',
width: 110,
listeners: [{
    getTip: function (v, metadata, rec, row, col, store) {
        return 'delete ' + rec.get('licenseid');
    },
    click: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex, item, event, record, row) {
        alert('here');
        this.fireEvent('LicenseIconClick', grid, record, 'delete');
    }
}],
renderer: function(value, metadata, record){
    if(record.get('licenseid') == 'atlas_usx_evaluation') {
        return "<img src='./images/atlas/icons/blue/settings-close-b.png'>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Action Column](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Action) does not have and therefore does not fire a click event.

Use the **handler** function and **getClass** instead

```
    xtype:'actioncolumn',
    width:50,
    items: [{
        tooltip: 'Edit',
        handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
            var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
            alert("Edit " + rec.get('firstname'));
            this.fireEvent('LicenseIconClick', grid, record, 'delete');
            //grid.doLayout(); //maybe... I'm not sure if it is necessary 
        },
        getClass: function(v, meta, rec) {
            if (record.get('licenseid') == 'atlas_usx_evaluation') {
                return 'settingCloseA';
            } else {
                return 'settingCloseB';
            }
        }
    }]
```

CSS classes

```
.x-action-col-cell img.settingCloseA {
    background-image: url("./images/atlas/icons/blue/settings-close-a.png");
}

.x-action-col-cell img.settingCloseB {
    background-image: url("./images/atlas/icons/blue/settings-close-b.png");
}
```

With getClass you can dynamically apply a css class with the icon you want. 
In the handler function you can fire your event.

Comment: getClass() is not being called. I tried putting it at the action column level as well, still no luck.

Comment: I got getClass() working, but the css does not seem to result in the icon image being rendered.

Comment: Can you show me which HTML code is generated? Maybe the css classes doesn't match...